# Converting String to TByteDynArray

Tags: delphi

I have a `String` object in Delphi. I want to convert that to `TByteDynArray`. I have tried the implementation below.But while debugging I find that `binaryData` is empty after the assignment.What am I doing wrong?

```
procedure convertStringToTByteDynArray;
var
  binaryData:TByteDynArray;
  Data: String;

begin
   Data := '8080100B1D472';
  //Copy over string to TByteDynArray
  SetLength(binaryData,Length(Data));
  Move(Data[1],binaryData,Length(Data)); 
end
```

Comment: Do you know what encoding you want to use?

Answer (score 4):

The size of `Char` is 1 byte in Delphi 2007 and earlier, but is 2 bytes in Delphi 2009 and later.  In the latter case, the code will put UTF-16 data into the bytearray, but will only copy half of the characters.

The core mistake you are making is that passing `binarydata` by itself to `Move()` passes the memory location of the variable itself, which is just a pointer to other memory.  Passing `binarydata[0]` instead passes the memory location of the first element of the allocated memory that the `TByteDynArray` is pointing at.  That is what you need to pass instead.

I also added a `Length()` check that avoids some rangecheck errors when those are enabled.

```
procedure convertStringToTByteDynArray;
var
  binaryData: TByteDynArray;
  Data: String;
begin
  Data := '8080100B1D472';
  //Copy over string to TByteDynArray
  SetLength(binaryData, Length(Data) * sizeof(Char));
  if Length(Data) > 0 then
    Move(Data[1], binaryData[0], Length(Data) * sizeof(Char)); 
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
procedure convertStringToTByteDynArray;
var
  binaryData: TByteDynArray;
  Data: String;
begin
  Data := '8080100B1D472';
  //Copy over string to TByteDynArray
  SetLength(binaryData, Length(Data) * sizeof(Char));
  Move(PChar(Data)^, PByte(binaryData)^, Length(binaryData)); 
end;
```

Comment: Or avoid the `if` with `Move(Pointer(Data)^, Pointer(BinaryData)^, Length(BinaryData))` because `if` is only needed to fit in with range checking.

Comment: Worth mentioning I think is that in the version of **Move** I am looking at (Delphi 7 - more recent versions not immediately to hand), it checks for a NIL *source*, but not a NIL *destination* (which will result in an access violation).  i.e. when using **Move**, an **if** to guard against a NIL source (empty *Data* in this case) is redundant.  However, guarding against a NIL *destination* may still be required (tho not in this case since the implementation of the convert... function ensures that the destination (*binaryData*) will only be NIL if Data is also NIL, i.e. empty).

Comment: @Deltics If the length is zero, surely neither of the first two args are de-referenced

Comment: Binary data in both cases is dereferenced before passing it to move, in the parameter preparation (either by the [0] or the ^)

Comment: @Marco No is not. The address is passed. Dereferencing happens inside Move.

Comment: @David, yes you're right.  As I say, in this specific case the issue doesn't arise but for the general case of using **Move()** you *may* need to guard (either explicitly or indirectly as a result of the implementation, as in this case) against a non-NIL *destination* where the source is non-NIL or count > 0 (conditions that you do *not* need to guard for).