# Convert TByteDynArray to string

Tags: delphi

I'm working with web service and I have a problem with ***an invalid character was found in text content***. I don't have much experience with encoding so I decided to pass the data as `TByteDynArray`. Here is the code I use from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36413046/5134294).

```
class function StringHelper.StringToByteArray(value: string): TByteDynArray;
begin   
  SetLength(Result, Length(value) * SizeOf(Char));    
  if Length(value) > 0 then
  begin
    Move(value[1], Result[0], Length(value) * SizeOf(Char));
  end;
end;
```

I had success with converting `string` to `TByteDynArray`, but I don't know how to convert it back from `TByteDynArray` to `string`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than copying the raw UTF16 bytes it is generally preferable to use the `TEncoding` class to perform such operations. And you might take this opportunity to become a little more proficient in text encodings.

So, you can use

```
bytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

to obtain the text as UTF8 encoded bytes.

In the opposite direction use

```
str := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

I've picked the UTF8 encoding here, but the encoding choice is yours. See the documentation for [`TEncoding`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding) for all the options.

The code in your question implicitly obtains UTF16 bytes because that's the raw string encoding in Delphi. I suspect that you used that encoding not out of any particular choice. However, if it is important to use UTF16 then change the code above to use `TEncoding.Unicode`.

Usually, however, UTF8 is a sound choice because it tends to be space efficient.

Comment: I'm using using TBytes now instead of TByteDynArray. thanks.. fully tested and its working..

Comment: @Ago: recently (I think it was in version10.3), TByteDynArray was aliased with TBytes or TArray<Byte>, and TBytes is generally the right type to use for a dynamic array of bytes, nowadays.